# Shorthand if needed to be in round brackets?

Tags: javascript

I have declared x and y as numbers like this:

```
var x = 5;
var y = 0;
```

And then I want to use for loop.
It's working fine if I have code like this:

```
for(let i = y; i < ((x == 5) ? x : x); i++) {
    console.log(i, x);
};
```

But when I remove round brackets around shortened if, then for is going endlessly. Why? Example below:

```
for(let i = y; i < (x == 5) ? x : x; i++) {
    console.log(i, x);
};
```

Comment: you may have a look to [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence).

Comment: check BODMAS rule

Comment: @vinayak_shahdeo BODMAS is only applicable for mathematical expressions, this is a JavaScript expression, so you cannot use the same rule, since it does not account for a conditional operator or comparison.

Answer (score 1):

The condition in the middle part of a for loop is checked for truthyness on each iteration.

Omitting the brackets, `i < (x == 5) ? x : x` is evaluated as

if `i` is smaller than `(x == 5)`, return `x`, otherwise return `x`

So, an integer is being compared to a boolean, which doesn't make much sense in the first place, but apart from that, the condition always evaluates to `x`, which is truthy (unless you gave it a value of 0). So the loop will run on and on forever.

Answer (score 1):

You need to break down your code first

```
i < ((x == 5) ? x : x)
```

this expression is evaluated by compiler as

```
((x == 5) ? x : x)
```

compare this and whatever the result is compare with i.

Whereas

```
i < (x == 5) ? x : x
```

this is compared as

```
i < (x == 5)
```

and then compare the result and get value of x.
So the condition becomes true in loop as you get value of x every time regardless of value of i and you get endless loop

Answer (score 0):

According to the [order of precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) the comparison (`<`) is higher on the list than the conditional operator (`... ? ... : ...)`.

So the order of evaluation of `i < (x == 5) ? x : x` is actually `(i < (x == 5)) ? x : x` or

1. Evaluate `x == 5`.
2. Evaluate `i < resultFromFirstStep`.
3. Return `x` if the comparison is `true`.
4. Return `x` otherwise.

Step 3 and 4 happen to be the same here. So, since the result would *always* be truthy (`x` is `5`), the loop continues forever.

Answer (score 0):

The [conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) operates like so:

> condition ? exprIfTrue : exprIfFalse

... in your first example the `condition` part is: `(x == 5)`, which then results in `x` (5), making your `for` loop condition evaluate to so:

```
for(let i = y; i < 5; i++) {
```

and so, your loop will loop for `5` iterations.

However, in your second example, your `condition` part is: `i < (x == 5)`, which evaluates to `i < true` where `true` is treated as `1`, and so `i < 1` is `true`, thus resulting in your `for` loop conditon being:

```
for(let i = y; 5; i++) {
```

As you are always returning `5` (which is a truthy values) no matter what from your ternary, your for loop will loop forever.